# driverless ai cannot import csv data

Tags: h2o, driverless-ai

I tried to import my data in csv format but it took forever to import and I cannot do anything except waiting. 
The number of rows and columns of data is 1,705 and 502, respectively. All variables except target and date are numeric type. The data size is only 12MB.

I do not know how many hours I will have to wait to import the data.
Please advise what I can do to try this product on my data.

Comment: There really isn't any way to help with this question as it is written.  Need the dataset or logs.

Comment: I am sorry to raise the question ambiguously because it is my first question. I solved the problem. The cause is that the numric value in the csv file is read as a categorical variable, even though it is a decimal number. I changed the format to numric directly in the csv file. I wrote that data in R and I do not seem to recognize numeric as numeric in csv file. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Fortunately, the problem is resolved.

If my data contains Inf, importing took a lot of time. I replaced Inf with a value, so I was importing quickly :)